# Storing variables in a theme outside preprocessing

Tags: 7, theming

I have some variables that I want to store in my theme, but I cannot always use `theme_preprocess()` to set and subsequently gain access to them.

What is the best way to do this?

I would like to **not** use a module, but with my experience in the past, a module has a `hook_install()` where an can use `variable_set()`; Is there anything similar for a theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, but Drupal has the concept of theme settings, which allow to configure a given theme with variables.

See http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-add-theme-settings-drupal-7 for a great introduction to them.

And according to [theme_get_setting()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_get_setting/7), you can for example store defaults in your theme's .info file, something like

```
settings[your_setting] = the_value
```

Should work.